# Duplicate FileVault setup using using fdesetup

Tags: filevault, macos, recovery

I upgraded to OSX 10.10 Yosemite yesterday, and accepted Apple's offer to encrypt my hard drive as a part of the upgrade process. However, Apple did not offer me a recovery key and did not offer to store a recovery key for me on their own server. Is there a way for me to obtain those features without [decrypting+encrypting](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4790)?

I do know that I can set a personal recovery key from the terminal using:

```
sudo fdesetup changerecovery -personal
```

but what about saving a recovery key with Apple? My guess is that the OS upgrade did not do this for me:

```
sudo fdesetup hasinstitutionalrecoverykey
Password:
false
```

Trying `changerecovery -institutional` seems to require configuration before usage:

```
Error: Institutional recovery key could not be added or changed.
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd like to point out is that `institutional` has everything to do with your school, company, or other organization which manages your computer.

If that doesn't apply to you (and you'd know if it did) then rest assured that `hasinstitutionalrecoverykey` doesn't apply to you.

I suspect that your drive is encrypted & backed with your AppleID. To confirm, run `sudo fdesetup list -extended` and look for an `iCloud User` listing.